# sql syntax error in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcommand

I've the following vb.net function which have a syntax error in the sql commandtext that i can't seem to figure out

```
Private Sub addsupporderidsinbookedtoinprocess()
        Try
            Dim cnn3 As New SqlConnection(connetionString)
            Dim sqlcmd3 As New SqlCommand("SELECT supporderidinprocess FROM ordersinprocess", cnn3)
            sqlcmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ordersinprocess(supporderidinprocess) VALUES(SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('[supporder]'))"
            cnn3.Open()
            sqlcmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlcmd3.Parameters.Clear()
            cnn3.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

the error is in this part

```
...VALUES(SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('[supporder]'))
```

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no `VALUES` keyword in `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement. Try something like this,

```
INSERT INTO ordersinprocess(supporderidinprocess) 
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('[supporder]')
```